# Not writing to file using BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java

Not writing content to file. Why ?

```
package JavaIO;
import java.io.*;
public class BufferedOutputStream {
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{    
         FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("/home/ebryx/myFile.txt");    
         BufferedOutputStream bout=new BufferedOutputStream(fout);    
         String s="I am Writing to file.";    
         byte b[]=s.getBytes();    
         bout.write(b);    
         bout.flush();    
         bout.close();       
         System.out.println("success");    
    }    
}
```

giving error at line 6 that remove argument from BufferedOutputStream or write constructor for it
and at line 9,10 giving error that method write(b) and flush() are not defined for type BufferedOutputStream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of your class equals the one in the `java.io` package you're trying to use.
You have 2 options:

1)
Rename your class into `MyBufferedOutputStream` or something you like more.

2)
Change line 6 as follows:
`java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout=new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(fout);`

Comment: Thanx bro! Robert Kock